# Pandas: Merge hierarchical data

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe

I am looking for a way to merge data that has a complex hierarchy into a pandas `DataFrame`. This hierarchy comes about by different inter-dependencies within the data. E.g. there are parameters which define how the data was produced, then there are time-dependent observables, spatially dependent observables, and observables that depend on both time and space.

To be more explicit: Suppose that I have the following data.

```
#  Parameters
t_max = 2
t_step = 15
sites = 4

# Purely time-dependent
t = np.linspace(0, t_max, t_step)
f_t = t**2 - t

# Purely site-dependent
position = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]])  # (x, y)
site_weight = np.arange(sites)

# Time-, and site-dependent.
occupation = np.arange(t_step*sites).reshape((t_step, sites))

# Time-, and site-, site-dependent
correlation = np.arange(t_step*sites*sites).reshape((t_step, sites, sites))
```

(In the end I would, of course, have many of these sets of data. One for each set of parameters.)

Now, I would like to stash all this into a pandas `DataFrame`. I imagine the final result to look something like this:

```
| ----- parameters ----- | -------------------------------- observables --------------------------------- |
|                        |                                        | ---------- time-dependent ----------- |
|                        | ----------- site-dependent --- )       ( ------------------------ |            |
|                        |                                | - site2-dependent - |                         |
| sites | t_max | t_step | site | r_x | r_y | site weight | site2 | correlation | occupation | f_t | time |
```

I suppose that the partially overlapping hierarchies may be impossible to achieve. It's okay if they are implicit, in the sense that I can get e.g. all site-dependent data by indexing the DataFrame in a specific way.

Also, please feel free to tell me if you think that there is a better way of arranging this data in Pandas.

#### Question

How can I construct a `DataFrame` that contains all the above data, and somehow reflects the inter-dependencies (e.g. `f_t` depends on `time`, but not on `site`). And all that in a way that is sufficiently generic, such that it is easy to add, or remove certain observables, with possibly new inter-dependencies. (E.g. a quantity that depends on a second time-axis, like a time-time-correlation.)

---

### What I got so far

In the following I will show you how far I've gotten on my own. However, I don't think that this is the ideal way of achieving the above. Especially, since it lacks generality with respect to adding, or removing certain observables.

#### Indices

Given the above data I started out by defining all the multi-indices that I am going to need.

```
ind_time = pd.Index(t, name='time')
ind_site = pd.Index(np.arange(sites), name='site')
ind_site_site = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ind_site, ind_site], names=['site', 'site2'])
ind_time_site = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ind_time, ind_site], names=['time', 'site'])
ind_time_site_site = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ind_time, ind_site, ind_site], names=['time', 'site', 'site2'])
```

#### Individual `DataFrame`s

Next, I created data-frames of the individual chunks of data.

```
df_parms = pd.DataFrame({'t_max': t_max, 't_step': t_step, 'sites': sites}, index=[0])
df_time = pd.DataFrame({'f_t': f_t}, index=ind_time)
df_position = pd.DataFrame(position, columns=['r_x', 'r_y'], index=ind_site)
df_weight = pd.DataFrame(site_weight, columns=['site weight'], index=ind_site)
df_occupation = pd.DataFrame(occupation.flatten(), index=ind_time_site, columns=['occupation'])
df_correlation = pd.DataFrame(correlation.flatten(), index=ind_time_site_site, columns=['correlation'])
```

The `index=[0]` in `df_parms` seems necessary because otherwise Pandas complains about scalar values only. In reality I would probably replace it by a time-stamp of when this particular simulation was run. That would at least convey some useful information.

#### Merge Observables

With the data-frames available, I join all the observables into one big `DataFrame`.

```
df_all_but_parms = pd.merge(
  pd.merge(
    pd.merge(
      df_time.reset_index(),
      df_occupation.reset_index(),
      how='outer'
    ),
    df_correlation.reset_index(),
    how='outer'
  ),
  pd.merge(
    df_position.reset_index(),
    df_weight.reset_index(),
    how='outer'
  ),
  how='outer'
)
```

This is the bit that I like the least in my current approach. The `merge` function only works on pairs of data-frames, and it requires them to have at least one common column. So, I have to be careful about the order of joining my data-frames, and if I were to add an orthogonal observable then I could not merge it with the other data because they would not share a common column. Is there one function available that can achieve the same result with just one single call on a list of data-frames? I tried `concat` but it wouldn't merge common columns. So, I ended up with lots of duplicate `time`, and `site` columns.

#### Merge All Data

Finally, I merge my data with the parameters.

```
pd.concat([df_parms, df_all_but_parms], axis=1, keys=['parameters', 'observables'])
```

The end-result, so far, looks like this:

```
         parameters                 observables                                                                       
              sites  t_max  t_step         time       f_t  site  occupation  site2  correlation  r_x  r_y  site weight
    0             4      2      15     0.000000  0.000000     0           0      0            0    0    0            0
    1           NaN    NaN     NaN     0.000000  0.000000     0           0      1            1    0    0            0
    2           NaN    NaN     NaN     0.000000  0.000000     0           0      2            2    0    0            0
    3           NaN    NaN     NaN     0.000000  0.000000     0           0      3            3    0    0            0
    4           NaN    NaN     NaN     0.142857 -0.122449     0           4      0           16    0    0            0
    ..          ...    ...     ...          ...       ...   ...         ...    ...          ...  ...  ...          ...
    235         NaN    NaN     NaN     1.857143  1.591837     3          55      3          223    1    1            3
    236         NaN    NaN     NaN     2.000000  2.000000     3          59      0          236    1    1            3
    237         NaN    NaN     NaN     2.000000  2.000000     3          59      1          237    1    1            3
    238         NaN    NaN     NaN     2.000000  2.000000     3          59      2          238    1    1            3
    239         NaN    NaN     NaN     2.000000  2.000000     3          59      3          239    1    1            3
```

As you can see this does not work very well, since only the first row is actually assigned the parameters. All the other rows just have `NaN`s in place of the parameters. But, since these are the parameters of all of that data, they should also be contained in all the other rows of this data-frame.

As a small side question: How smart would pandas be if I were to store the above data-frame in hdf5. Would I end up with lots of duplicated data, or would it avoid duplicate storage?

---

### Update

Thanks to [Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24758685/841562) I was able to push all my data into one data-frame with a generic merge. The basic idea is, that all my observables already have a few common columns. Namely, the parameters.

First I add the parameters to all my observables' data-frames.

```
all_observables = [ df_time, df_position, df_weight, df_occupation, df_correlation ]
flat = map(pd.DataFrame.reset_index, all_observables)
for df in flat:
    for c in df_parms:
        df[c] = df_parms.loc[0,c]
```

And then I can merge all of them together by reduction.

```
df_all = reduce(lambda a, b: pd.merge(a, b, how='outer'), flat)
```

The result of which has the desired form:

```
         time       f_t  sites  t_max  t_step  site  r_x  r_y  site weight  occupation  site2  correlation
0    0.000000  0.000000      4      2      15     0    0    0            0           0      0            0
1    0.000000  0.000000      4      2      15     0    0    0            0           0      1            1
2    0.000000  0.000000      4      2      15     0    0    0            0           0      2            2
3    0.000000  0.000000      4      2      15     0    0    0            0           0      3            3
4    0.142857 -0.122449      4      2      15     0    0    0            0           4      0           16
5    0.142857 -0.122449      4      2      15     0    0    0            0           4      1           17
6    0.142857 -0.122449      4      2      15     0    0    0            0           4      2           18
..        ...       ...    ...    ...     ...   ...  ...  ...          ...         ...    ...          ...
233  1.857143  1.591837      4      2      15     3    1    1            3          55      1          221
234  1.857143  1.591837      4      2      15     3    1    1            3          55      2          222
235  1.857143  1.591837      4      2      15     3    1    1            3          55      3          223
236  2.000000  2.000000      4      2      15     3    1    1            3          59      0          236
237  2.000000  2.000000      4      2      15     3    1    1            3          59      1          237
238  2.000000  2.000000      4      2      15     3    1    1            3          59      2          238
239  2.000000  2.000000      4      2      15     3    1    1            3          59      3          239
```

By re-indexing the data, the hierarchy becomes a bit more apparent:

```
df_all.set_index(['t_max', 't_step', 'sites', 'time', 'site', 'site2'], inplace=True)
```

which results in

```
                                             f_t  r_x  r_y  site weight  occupation  correlation
t_max t_step sites time     site site2                                                          
2     15     4     0.000000 0    0      0.000000    0    0            0           0            0
                                 1      0.000000    0    0            0           0            1
                                 2      0.000000    0    0            0           0            2
                                 3      0.000000    0    0            0           0            3
                   0.142857 0    0     -0.122449    0    0            0           4           16
                                 1     -0.122449    0    0            0           4           17
                                 2     -0.122449    0    0            0           4           18
...                                          ...  ...  ...          ...         ...          ...
                   1.857143 3    1      1.591837    1    1            3          55          221
                                 2      1.591837    1    1            3          55          222
                                 3      1.591837    1    1            3          55          223
                   2.000000 3    0      2.000000    1    1            3          59          236
                                 1      2.000000    1    1            3          59          237
                                 2      2.000000    1    1            3          59          238
                                 3      2.000000    1    1            3          59          239
```

Comment: you are trying to shove an awful lot in a single frame. think of a multi-index (say on the index), enumerates the cartesian product of the levels. is your data n-dimensional like this? a multi index in the columns is really just a labeling convention.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Do you suggest I should store these things in separate data-frames? Or do you suggest, that I should add multi-indices in the final table for better structuring of the data?

Comment: why don't u show some operations that you would like to do (what kind of selections, numeric ops and such). best if u can give an example output

Comment: I would not include the ``df_parms`` in your frame; ``df_all_but_parms`` looks pretty good as is

Comment: @Jeff Since I haven't gotten the data-frame working, I don't have any code using it, yet. But, conceptually here's what I would like to do with it. First, I would like to plot observables as functions of `time` with certain parameters, or site-indices in the plot-legend. I would also like to do some basic arithmetic with these, e.g. `kinetic_energy + interaction_energy`. Or, I would like to add together the site-wise occupation, weighted by the site-weights, and then plot it as a function of time.

Comment: @Jeff The reason why I wanted to add `df_parms` into the final frame is that I'm going to have many different instances of the above set of data at the same time. And then I might wish to plot the occupation at `time=0` as a function of some parameter.

Comment: @Jeff Yet another reason for mashing all this stuff into one data-frame is that I was hoping for an easy way to store all this data in an hdf5 file in a structured way, but still be able to select certain items by a parameter. E.g. I could wish to load and plot all the `d_f` for the parameter range where `t_max` is between 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do something like this, putting `df_parms` as your index. This way you can easily concat more frames with different parms.

```
In [67]: pd.set_option('max_rows',10)

In [68]: dfx = df_all_but_parms.copy()
```

You need to assign the columns to the frame (you can also directly construct a multi-index, but this is starting from your data).

```
In [69]: for c in df_parms.columns:
             dfx[c] = df_parms.loc[0,c]

In [70]: dfx
Out[70]: 
         time       f_t  site  occupation  site2  correlation  r_x  r_y  site weight  sites  t_max  t_step
0    0.000000  0.000000     0           0      0            0    0    0            0      4      2      15
1    0.000000  0.000000     0           0      1            1    0    0            0      4      2      15
2    0.000000  0.000000     0           0      2            2    0    0            0      4      2      15
3    0.000000  0.000000     0           0      3            3    0    0            0      4      2      15
4    0.142857 -0.122449     0           4      0           16    0    0            0      4      2      15
..        ...       ...   ...         ...    ...          ...  ...  ...          ...    ...    ...     ...
235  1.857143  1.591837     3          55      3          223    1    1            3      4      2      15
236  2.000000  2.000000     3          59      0          236    1    1            3      4      2      15
237  2.000000  2.000000     3          59      1          237    1    1            3      4      2      15
238  2.000000  2.000000     3          59      2          238    1    1            3      4      2      15
239  2.000000  2.000000     3          59      3          239    1    1            3      4      2      15

[240 rows x 12 columns]
```

Set the index (this returns a new object)

```
In [71]: dfx.set_index(['sites','t_max','t_step'])
Out[71]: 
                        time       f_t  site  occupation  site2  correlation  r_x  r_y  site weight
sites t_max t_step                                                                                 
4     2     15      0.000000  0.000000     0           0      0            0    0    0            0
            15      0.000000  0.000000     0           0      1            1    0    0            0
            15      0.000000  0.000000     0           0      2            2    0    0            0
            15      0.000000  0.000000     0           0      3            3    0    0            0
            15      0.142857 -0.122449     0           4      0           16    0    0            0
...                      ...       ...   ...         ...    ...          ...  ...  ...          ...
            15      1.857143  1.591837     3          55      3          223    1    1            3
            15      2.000000  2.000000     3          59      0          236    1    1            3
            15      2.000000  2.000000     3          59      1          237    1    1            3
            15      2.000000  2.000000     3          59      2          238    1    1            3
            15      2.000000  2.000000     3          59      3          239    1    1            3

[240 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, putting the parameters into the index is probably a good idea. Do you know if there is a better way of constructing `df_all_but_parms`? Ideally, just one call on a sequence of data-frames that merges on common columns automatically.

Comment: It seems messy, but based on your data might not be an easier way. you can prob get away with ``df_position.join(df_weight)`` though (its the same as your merge, but 'cleaner')

Comment: I was able to merge them all together with generic merge operatinos by using your answer and adding the parameters as common columns to all data-frames. You can see the details in my edited question.

Comment: gr8! keep in mind that you can partially ``reset_index`` when you need (to bring a level from the index to column space, use ``levels`` parameter)